# Воспринимать строку, как разные команды

Tags: c#

есть некая потребность в том, чтобы отправлять данные серверу, но он же не понимает, что конкретно с ними нужно делать? Может, регистрация; может, логин; а может вообще - отправка комментария.
Я думал над этим и решил использовать два символа в конце строки. Например, клиент отправляет свои данные для регистрации:

```
{"Login":"RandomLogin","Password":"RandomPassord","Email":"RandomGmail@gmail.com"}
```

Серверу же нужно осознать, что это не публикация комментария или не отправка запроса на лайк? Я прибегнул к тому, чтобы в конце таких данных оставались команды. И из примера выше стало:

```
{"Login":"RandomLogin","Password":"RandomPassord","Email":"RandomGmail@gmail.com"} -R
```

Как видите, теперь в конце пишутся два символа "-R". Я их анализирую как символы, добавляю в string, и если при проверке это команда регистрации, то сервер запустит метод регистрации и начнёт воспринимать данные, как данные для регистрации.
Вопрос: правильно ли я всё вообще сделал? Есть ли более простые способы? Если нет, то вопрос следующий: можно ли упростить проверку двух символов, каким либо образом?

Заранее всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: Добавьте в json `"Action":"Register"`

Comment: Совсем не мог до этого додуматься, спасибо Вам!

Comment: Не вешайте одну логику на один метод, это совершенно неверный подход. Как минимум, тут страдает логика, из которой уже страдает удобство использование, лишние свойства в JSON (классе), и так далее. Вот условно, отправляете комментарий, будете отправлять логин, пароль, почту, id темы, текст комментария, и т.д.? Согласитесь, бред. Даже если это будет `NULL` данные, это все равно метод с лишним набором свойств. Так что, разделяйте. Если это сайт - разные API методы, если это ваш сервер и там один приемщик, то интерфейс и наследование в помощь, а в JSON стандартный `"$type" : "Comment"`.